# iOS: Error deleting contacts from Address book: [CNDataMapperContactStore executeSaveRequest:error:]

Tags: ios, contacts, abaddressbook

I'm trying to implement a deletion of contacts in the address book but I'm getting the following errors.

Here is my implementation:

```
 CNMutableContact *contact = [[cnContacts objectAtIndex:i] copy];
        [cnContacts removeObjectAtIndex:i];


        CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
        [request deleteContact:contact];

        NSError *error;
        if (![self.ContactStore executeSaveRequest:request error:&error]) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error.description);
            }
        }
```

On this line:

```
if (![self.ContactStore executeSaveRequest:request error:&error]) {
```

I'm getting this error in the console:

-[CNContact setSnapshot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145de3940

Also this errors are showing:

```
Contacts`-[CNDataMapperContactStore executeSaveRequest:error:]:
libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread:
```

[image]
[image]

Any of you knows why of this errors or what I'm doing wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this API, but looking around I see that:

```
[request deleteContact:contact];
```

requires a `CNMutableContact` object and you have made it immutable by using `copy`:

```
 CNMutableContact *contact = [[cnContacts objectAtIndex:i] copy];
 // contact is actually a CNContact object
```

You want `mutableCopy`, however I don't see a need to create a copy at all, assuming `cnContacts` contains `CNMutableContact` instances, as removing it from the array will not destroy the object as you still have a reference to it locally.

I can only assume `snapshot` is private property of `CNMutableContact` which is not available on `CNContact`, and hence the *unrecognized selector* exception (I see nothing about this property in the class reference).